# Get ROS 2 JavaScript message object at run-time with rclnodejs

Tags: ros2, robotwebtools

I need a way to retrieve a JavaScript object, at run-time with [rclnodejs](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rclnodejs), which corresponds to the message on a topic. Instead of hard-coding the properties (or attributes) of the ROS 2 message in my code, I need to retrieve it. For example, my code wants to publish a message onto the `cmd_vel` topic. The code has the type of the message as `geometry_msgs/msg/TwistStamped`. I'm looking for the function or the object in rclnodejs which will return an initialized JavaScript object which can then be passed to the rclnodejs `publish` function.

I've found both `createMessage()` and `createMessageObject()` but they're not quite what I need. `createMessage()` will return a complete, initialized ROS message object, but is missing the `hasMember()` method. On the other hand, `createMessageObject()` doesn't include all of the message properties.